# Search Console reports article is indexed, "site:" operator doesn't. Why?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-index

One of my latest articles had gotten indexed and was showing as indexed via the "site:" operator too, but it is now showing as indexed in Console only, not via the "site:" parameter. What could possibly be the reason?

Comment: Google says that `site:` searches won't show everything.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller On that, Google says (here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/debug/search-operators/all-search-site), "If a URL is indexed in Google, it can show up in search results for site: queries that are related to the URL, however it's not guaranteed. If a URL doesn't show in a site: query, use the URL Inspection tool <b>to make sure the URL can be indexed and to submit the URL to indexing.</b> Also, double-check the query is correct; site:https://www.example.com doesn't return the same results as site:https://example.com/."  (Bolded statement is confusing it)

Answer (score 0):

I did my own research and went straight to Google's support pages, where on the page https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7474347?hl=en , I saw Google saying:

> "If the report says that the page **has been indexed**" [in my case,
> the exact words were "Submitted and Indexed"]
>
> "i. ​Check whether you (or someone else) successfully requested that
> the site or URL be removed from the index. Open the URL removal tool
> to look for approved requests of URL or site removal. If so, you can
> revoke the request.   ii. The page may have been dropped or omitted
> from the index for totally innocuous reasons. (The web is immense, and
> Google doesn't get to every page, though we try to!) Ask Google to
> recrawl your page.
>
> iii. Still having problems? Visit the Webmaster Forum and explain your
> problem (please be sure to describe the issue completely, and include
> links to your site)."

The first Google advice wasn't the issue (I confirmed this through the suggested URL removal tool), so I tried the second one (using "Request Indexing" inside Console) and am awaiting result (45 minutes since recrawl requested, not showing up as indexed via the "site:" parameter/operator at the time of this writing), but I now know (so do you) that after I (you) have tried all else, I am (you are) supposed to visit the Webmaster Forum and explain my (your) problem there in the hopes the solution will be found there in anybody's (possibly a Google staff member's) response.